# Add a hyphen after the first N charcters in a string and also remove a portion of a string that starts with #

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have a string similar to the following:

```
391c294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69#3640345
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
391c-294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69
```

As you will see, I want to add a hyphen after the first 4 characters only and then remove the `#` and all characters after it in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regex match is helpful here:

```bsh
str='391c294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69#3640345'
[[ "$str" =~ (.{4})([^#]+) ]] && new="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "$new"
```

```
391c-294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69
```

The [`BASH_REMATCH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) array holds the captured parts of the regex, and index 0 holds the part of the input that matched the whole regex.

Comment: Excellent solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansions.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
expected=391c-294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69
input='391c294eb646cd0f3068cc7ba945071d04327b0ccb181d901466ee3d79c6fe69#3640345'

result=${input%#*}  # Remove everything starting with the last #.
result=${result:0:4}-${result:4}  # Insert the dash.

[[ $result == $expected ]] && echo ok
```

If you want the first # instead, use `${input%%#*}`.